# Android Open GL fragment shader speed

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a fragment shader that's calculating RGB float values running on a Nexus 7.

If I run this shader with `gl_FragColor = vec4(c1,c2,c3,1.0);` - where c1, c2, and c3 are the three colours calculated - I get around 26 fps.

If I keep everything else the same - so all the calculations remain in place - and simply change to `gl_FragColor = vec4(c1,1.0,1.0,1.0);` I get 60 fps.

Should I expect that assigning these float values should take so long? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is very weird. Can you show us some more context? Post complete shaders, etc. The driver might optimize the calculations away because you don't use them...

Comment: See my response below. You're most probably right.

Comment: Nexus 7 (2012) or (2013)?  The former is Nvidia Tegra 3, the latter is Qualcomm Adreno 320.

Comment: The 2012 version. Does this make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `c2`,`c3` anywhere else, then when you remove them from the `gl_FragColor` the compiler will decide that it's not worth calculating them at all, and so it will optimize the calculations away.

We'd need to see how those `c2`,`c3` variables are calculated to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Just starting out with shaders so have copied from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldBGRR with the intention of seeing how the frame rates on tablets compared. Sounds like that might be the case. I was assuming they'd be calculated but then just not used for the vec4.

Comment: Not seen that website before. That's pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

*Vertical synchronization could be your problem*

Most probable cause of this is that v-sync is **on** in your graphics card settings (in this case mobile/tablet).

Turn it off and see it skyrocket. But I guess this is not possible. You can also measure the time it takes to render the frame and see that it is in fact much shorter than 1/60th of a second. So loads of time for logic code.

Comment: Yes ... the logic can clearly run at 60fps. I can prove that by running the algorithm but simply outputting 1.0f into the vec4. When I use the calculated values in the vec4 my fps drops off significantly. Can this be right?

Comment: Just as weston pointed out in his response. It might be the additional calculations behind the values that slow down the shader.